# SoupUI DS using groovy script parsing XML from URL

Tags: xml, groovy, singleton, datasource, soapui

I'm using SoapUI pro Datasource groovy script:

```
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult

@Singleton 
class UrlXmlParser {

    //def url = "http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/plant_catalog.xml"
    def slurper  = new XmlSlurper()

    GPathResult parse(String url){
//      def xmlText = url.toURL().text
//      def content = slurper.parseText(xmlText)
        slurper.parse(url)
    }
}

def allPlants = UrlXmlParser.parse("http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/plant_catalog.xml").PLANT

//
//log.info "it works"+allPlants.size()

def row = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["groovyDS"].currentRow

if(row < allPlants.size()){
    result["zone"]=content.PLANT[row].ZONE
    result["light"]=content.PLANT[row].LIGHT
    result["price"]=content.PLANT[row].PRICE

}
```

But I get an error because of the GPathResult:

```
No signature of method: static UrlXmlParser.parse() is applicable for
argument types: (java.lang.String) values:
[http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/plant_catalog.xml] Possible
solutions: parse(java.lang.String), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), wait(),
grep(), any(), wait(long)
```

Comment: i don't know soapui:s behaviour, but are you sure, that AST Transformations like `@Singleton` are handled at all?  Could you just write it as a regular class or closure?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer

```
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult

@Singleton 
class UrlXmlParser {

    def slurper  = new XmlSlurper()

    GPathResult parse(String url){
//      def xmlText = url.toURL().text
//      def content = slurper.parseText(xmlText)
        slurper.parse(url)
    }
}

def url = "http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/plant_catalog.xml"
def allPlants = UrlXmlParser.instance.parse(url).PLANT



def row = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["groovyDS"].currentRow

if(row < allPlants.size()){
    result["zone"]=content.PLANT[row].ZONE
    result["light"]=content.PLANT[row].LIGHT
    result["price"]=content.PLANT[row].PRICE

}
```